# SQL query GROUP BY not working as expected on w3 schools site accessed via Google Chome, works as expected via Firefox

Tags: sql, google-chrome, ubuntu, firefox, w3c

I tried running the following query from an ubuntu 18.04 machine on w3schools.com "*Try It Yourself*" SQL console from two different browsers -
1. **Google Chrome** (Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit))
2. **Firefox** (version 75.0 (64-bit)).

```
SELECT City, Country

FROM Customers

GROUP BY Country;
```

this query should not work when run, the same was observed on firefox.

```
Result on w3schools in Firefox  
Error in SQL:
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'City' as part of an aggregate function.
```

However, when the same query was executed in Google Chrome the following result was obtained.

```
Number of Records: 21

City                Country
Buenos Aires        Argentina
Graz                Austria
Bruxelles           Belgium
São Paulo           Brazil
Tsawassen           Canada
København           Denmark
Oulu                Finland
Strasbourg          France
Berlin              Germany
Cork                Ireland
Torino              Italy
México D.F.         Mexico
Stavern             Norway
Walla               Poland
Lisboa              Portugal
Madrid              Spain
Luleå               Sweden
Bern                Switzerland
London              UK
Eugene              USA
Caracas             Venezuela
```

I do not understand what is happening under the hood when the query was run on w3school.com via Google Chrome.

*Try It Yourself*: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript of w3schools is actually performing these operations against SQLite database. When you load the page, the script *w3Database.js* is initializing database. The implementation of SQLite in FireFox is slightly different than implementation in Chrome. That's why you see this difference.

Feel free to report a bug for Chrome.